# How do I deal with this error with Backbone Router?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

This is my application.js file

```
window.App = {
init: function() {
     this.router = new PackageViewer();
       Backbone.history.start();
   }

};
```

This is calling the other packageviewer.js that's here

```
window.PackageViewer = new Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes : {
   '':'home'
},

initialize:function(){
   this.collection = new Package();
},

home:function(){
   $('body').append("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
 } 
});
```

And here is my index.html's script tag that is inside `<body>`

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function (){            
    App.init();

});
</script>
```

When I run this I get `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'parent.apply(this, arguments)')`

I cannot comprehend this. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this:

```
window.PackageViewer = new Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes : {
   '':'home'
}
```

to this:

```
window.PackageViewer = Backbone.Router.extend({
 routes : {
   '':'home'
}
```

Because here you're supposed to be just extending Backbone.Router, not creating a new instance.

You correctly create a new instance in your App.init when you call `this.router = new PackageViewer();

I tested this with a dummy Package Model and Collection and it worked.

```
window.Package = Backbone.Model.extend({
});

window.Packages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Package  
});
```